# How to extent Report in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, report, automated-tests, testng-eclipse

I am using HTML publisher plugin in Jenkins, and also i'm using ExtentReport with Eclipse to generate reports.

How to generate those reports (ExtentReport) in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 5):

As you are already using HTML publisher plugin in Jenkins.

Get through this official documentation link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

[image: This is the configuration i have used for my project. Provide relative url of report referencing to your actual project which you are making in eclipse/intellij tool]